# Windows Authentication problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, authentication

I have a website setup to use two different bindings in iis. When visiting one url windows authentication works, but when using the other url it prompts the user for their login credentials (and doesn't work)

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Not sure if you have the same issue, but in my case that somtimes happens when I try to connect locally to the website with host header set. If I test the URL remotely the authentication works fine. Not sure about why, but perhaps this could be your problem too?

Comment: Are the two URLs within the same site? Are the pages in different folders?

Comment: The pages are within different sites. One site has a folder that has been made into an application folder which points to the other site. But it works if you visit the website with one url and not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a whole plethora of things:

- ACL permissions on the files/folder themselves.
- Impersonation on in one app and not another.
- IIS security settings allowing anonymous on one and integrated on the other with improper permissions, etc etc.

Check permissions are the same, web.config settings are the same for authentication, and IIS security settings are the same and that the user you are trying has permissions to the files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

What are your bindings and what windows authentication provider are you trying to use?

This is just a stab in the dark, since I don't have more information, but:

I know Negotiate:Kerberos doesn't work if you have a locally declared host and you're trying to delegate with Kerberos to another system (service layer etc) when your machine has been given AD privledges to delegate to the other system. AFAIK, the reason for that is that the origin that your request is coming from is a host that the domain doesn't know. It knows how to translate localhost, but not a custom hostname.